# AngularJS (Filter) : How to implement multi-keyword search on object attributes?

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

Check this jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mystikacid/hajo0c33/

I'm using the keyword in the input box to filter the objects to be shown. This works fine as far as I enter only one keyword. But if I try to filter by two keywords (for two attributes, example, my query is - 'Transformers 150V' as I want to look for those Transformers which use 150V, it does not show any result.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type='text' ng-model='query' placeholder = "Search" />
    <div ng-repeat="product in products | filter : query">
        {{product.name}} | 
        {{product.family}} | 
        {{product.amperage}} |
        {{product.volt}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){

$scope.products = [
    {
        name : '9T21S1050',
        family : 'Transformer',
        amperage : '20A',
        volt : '150V'
    },
    {
        name : '9T85B3092',
        family : 'Transformer',
        amperage : '15A',
        volt : '200V'
    },
    {
        name : 'AEU3182RCXAXB4',
        family : 'Panel Board',
        amperage : '30A',
        volt : '250V'
    },
    {
        name : 'AQU1182RCXAXB4',
        family : 'Panel Board',
        amperage : '25A',
        volt : '300V'
    },
    {
        name : 'AQU1422RCXAXT1',
        family : 'Panel Board',
        amperage : '35A',
        volt : '150V'
    }
]


});
```

I understand that I need to write a function for the filter, but I've not been able to make it work so far. Let me know if you'd like to see the function too.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i am creating a new filter that will give product if both value will be present in it.

```
var m = angular.module('yourModuleName');
m.filter('advancefilter', ['$filter', function($filter){
    return function(data, text){
        var textArr = text.split(' ');
        angular.forEach(textArr, function(test){
            if(test){
                  data = $filter('filter')(data, test);
            }
        });
        return data;
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Dont forget to add null check for text.